# ASP.NET MVC get content owner username

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, author

I'm trying to get username of the post owner. Here is what so far I've tried.

```
var model = db.Posts
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.PostDate)
            .Select(p => new PostViewModel
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Title = p.Title,
                Link = p.Link,
                Description = p.Description,
                Username = db.UserProfiles.Find(p.UserId).UserName
            }).ToList();
```

I am trying to get post from my domain model and store it to view model, and everything works except getting username by author id. I' getting this error:

```
Method 'Project.Models.UserProfile Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Project.Models.UserProfile]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Project.Models.UserProfile]'
```

So how I could get a username of the author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some way to navigate from a Post to a UserProfile. Use .Include() to pull in the necessary relationships and then access that. For example, if the Post has a navigable property called UserProfile, do the following.

```
var model = db.Posts
        .Include( "UserProfile" )
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.PostDate)
        .Select(p => new PostViewModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Title = p.Title,
            Link = p.Link,
            Description = p.Description,
            Username = p.UserProfile.UserName
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: So in my Post model instead of public int UserId { get; set; } I must have public UserProfile User{ get; set; } ?

Comment: If that's how your data is related, yes. Although it's not necessarily an "instead", you can have both the UserId property (for those times when you only need the UserId and a UserProfile property for those times when you want the whole UserProfile.